# HTML -> Fixed top, Flexible bottom with min-height and dynamic squared content

Tags: html, css

I'm really struggling to create css layout like this:

**Top row:** fixed size: Ex: 50px;

**Content:** the biggest square the current width can fit. So width = height for this one. It should respect the bottom row min-height.

**Bottom row:** take all remaining space available, and with min-height. Ex: 50px.

No scrollbar. The idea is to use the current screen the best way possible for any resolution. No javascript unless it's only possible with js.

Any ideas?

That's the best I've got so far:

```
   <div class="shell">
      <div class="header"></div>
      <div class="square"></div>
      <div class="footer"></div>
    </div>
```

css

```
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
.shell {
  background-color: #000000;
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: calc(100vh - 100px);
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.header {
  background-color: #0000ff;
  height: 50px;
}

.square {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #dc143c;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #00008b;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: I tried millions of combinations already. Should I post them all? There was a time when S.O. was about helping people :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use padding to get the aspect ratio:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
.shell {
  background-color: #000000;
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: calc(100vh - 100px);
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.header {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
}

.square {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.footer {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="shell">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Reference [here](https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/)

Comment: The footer size isn't 100% of remaining space, but 100% of entire container, but scroll isn't visible cause you hide it by `overflow: hidden`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question was already solved here:
[Make a div fill the height of the remaining screen space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space)

Mixed with your try:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  background-color: #000000;
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: calc(100vh - 100px);
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}


.box .row.header {
  flex: 0 1 50px;
  background-color: #0000ff;
}

.box .row.content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #dc143c;
}

.box .row.footer {
  flex: 0 1 40px;
  background-color: #00008b;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="row header">
  </div>
  <div class="row content">
  </div>
  <div class="row footer">
  </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/901s2kdL/

Comment: It doesn't work when the width is too small. If that happens, it's not a square anymore.

Answer (score 0):

> Content: the biggest square the current width can fit. So width =
> height for this one. It should respect the bottom row min-height.

If you want the biggest `square`, the `footer` `height` will be fixed and it will be equal to `min-height` always (and it should be), so it doesn't matter if you will set it's `height` to `100%` or `50px`. `max-width` of square determining really sizes. If you look at this `max-width: calc(100vh - 100px)`, the `- 100px` part is the real remaining space including `header` and `footer`, so if the `header` `height` is set to `50px`, the `footer` `height` is also `50px`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.shell {
  background-color: black;
}

.header {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.square {
  max-width: calc(100vh - 100px);
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: green;
}

.square:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.footer {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="shell">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It stayed a square, but the bottom part has a fixe height instead of taking all remaining space available.

Comment: I've updated the post about explanation why it doesn't matter if it's `100%` or `50px`.